# Given $\log_2(\log_3x)=\log_3(\log_4y)=\log_4(\log_2z)$, find $x+y+z$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

It seems so messy. I have no idea where to start. Can anyone share any ideas?

I found $x=3^{2^m}$, $y=4^{3^m}$ and $z=2^{4^m}$, and then I stopped again...

Sorry guys I misread the question... It should have been $\log_2(\log_3x)=\log_3(\log_4y)=\log_4(\log_2z)=0$... I am sorry...

Comment: Please avoid no-clue questions . How do you think you can find $(x + y + z)$ ?

Comment: @Anonymous I found $x=3^{2^m}$, $y=4^{3^m}$ and $z=2^{4^m}$, and then I stopped again...

Comment: ok , you can see the hints and try to figure it out !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember $\log_{b}(x)=y$ means that $b^{y}=x$.

So let $\log_2(\log_3x)=\log_3(\log_4y)=\log_4(\log_2z)=a$ then:

- $\log_2(\log_3x)=a\implies\log_3(x)=2^{a}\implies x=3^{2^{a}}$
- $\log_3(\log_4y)=a\implies\log_{4}(y)=3^{2}\implies y=4^{3^{a}}$
- $\log_4(\log_2z)=a\implies\log_{2}(z)=4^{a}\implies z=2^{3^a}.$

Thus $x+y+z=3^{2^{a}}+4^{3^{a}}+2^{3^{a}}$ and there are infinitely many solutions depending on $a.$

Taking $a=0$ we have $x+y+z=3+4+2=9$, , for $a=1$ you get $x+y+z=81$ for $a=2$ we have $x+y+z=262737$, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 equations over 3 variables, So there is no unique solution.

Although you may think, anyway $x+y+z$ can be constant, but:

$$\log_2 (\log_3 x) = \log_3 (\log_4 y) = \log_4 (\log_2 z) = t$$
$$\Longrightarrow x+y+z = 3^{2^t} + 4^{3^t} + 2^{4^t}$$

It's easy to see the right hand side can get any value in $(3,+\infty)$.

Maybe you must find its minimum, that is $3$.

Answer (score 1):

The hint:

Let $$\log_2\log_3x=\log_3\log_4y=\log_4\log_2z=0.$$
So $$x+y+z=9.$$
Let $$\log_2\log_3x=\log_3\log_4y=\log_4\log_2z=1.$$
So $$x+y+z\neq9.$$